# Private and public contacts

Tags: civimember

How can I set up Civi so that volunteers have only see private contacts but cannot see their details or their interactions (emails, calls etc).

Answer (score 2):

You're asking two different (but related) questions:

- How can I hide a group of contacts from a set of users?
- How can I show a group of contacts but hide their activities?

For the first question, you should:

- Make sure the non-privileged staff have a CMS role that does NOT have the "View All Contacts" or "Edit All Contacts" permissions.
- Add all the contacts they SHOULD have access to into one or more groups.
- Use [ACLs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/) to grant access ONLY to the contacts the staff should see.

If you want to allow a set of users to see contacts but not their activities:

- Install the [Activity Type ACL](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.activitytypeacl) extension.
- It's called an "ACL extension", but really this adds CMS permissions to roles so that you can deny contacts access to certain activity types.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up your Volunteers with a different CMS role and then set that role to not have access to Activities - but I suspect that is a blunter tool than you require. You probably need to expand your question to clarify what you mean by 'private contacts'

Comment: Well, as an user of Civi and in the same time part of the staff of the organisation using it could I define some of my contacts as private so that either nobody but me can access their details and the discussions (everybody can still see them on the contact list) or could I stop only Volunteers group from seeing the details and discussions of those contacts?

Comment: You might want to read up about using CiviCase as this automatically provides ACL so only the users with case roles can see the activities on that case. I think otherwise you might struggle to get the privacy you required

Comment: Hi Pete, do you know the the compatible version of CiviCRM this ACL extension works in? I've it installed in civiCRM 4.6.35 on Drupal but i can't find where to set the permissions, the ACL extension has automatically set all my activity types hidden so even as admin on the dev site, i don't see activity types on select list when adding new activity - Thanks

Comment: which "ACL extension" ? the one in Jon's answer?